# How can I choose which subscribed observers to be emitted?

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, signalr, subject

I have a service to communicate with server using SignalR. Service consumers subscribe to a Rxjs's Subject but I what I want is they should pass some additional data( a string in this case) and after service received data from server could choose which subscriber to be executed by calling next() method.

I tried to write a new subscribe method and store every subscription but there is no way to link subscriptions and observer. Here is my code :

```
private subscriptions = new Array<{registerationName:string,subscription:Subscription}>();
private receiver = new Subject(); 

public subscribe(registerationName:string ,next?: (value: {}) => void, error?: (error: any) => void): Subscription
{
     var s = this.receiver.subscribe(next,error);
     this.subscriptions.push({registerationName:registerationName,subscription:s});
     return s;
}
```

Obviously above approach does not work. What exactly I want to do is something like this :

```
this.receiver.observer.where(p=>p.registerationName==stringFromServer).next({...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I correctly understand your scenario this is solution you want:

Please, **better call that method you want `getMyData` or something specific instead** of subscribe, you can call subscribe to Observable which returns after `getMyData()` is called

```
private receiver = new Subject();

public getMyData<T>(registerationName: string): Observable<T> {
  return this.receiver.pipe(
    filter(
      ({ stringFromServer, data }) => stringFromServer === registerationName,
    ),
    map(({ stringFromServer, data }) => data),
  );
}
```

**When server data arrives call following:**

```
this.receiver.next({stringFromServer, data})
```

---

Now when data arrives and `receiver`-subject gets `next()`-ed, all the `getMyData()` observers with the specific `registrationName` will get `next()`-ed

**Now your usage becomes following:**

```
this.someService
  .getMyData('some registration name')
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you looking for

```
const events=new Map()
const addEvent=(event)=>{
   events.set(event,new Subject())
}

const fireEvent=(event,param)=>{
   events.get(event).next(param)
}
const getEvent=(event)=>events.get(event)

addEvent('walk')
fireEvent('walk',2)
getEvent('walk').subscribe(console.log)
```